# QGIS plugin install error message

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error

I am encountering the following error message in QGIS when trying to install some dependencies for a plugin called GeoTrace:

IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

I am using QGIS 2.18.15 64 bit on Windows. This error message appears in the stack trace and message log when I try to open GeoTrace in QGIS. GeoTrace uses Numpy, Matplotlib, mplstereonet, scikit-image. QGIS comes bundled with Numpy and Matplotlib.

Comment: What plugin? What dependencies? Why does it need dependencies? What operating system? Where do you see this error?

Comment: Please don't add extra info in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: Have you installed mplstereonet, scikit-image? Or is that what you are asking, how do I install the dependencies?

Comment: I have not installed these, and I am unsure how to do so.